# How to determine threshold in Sigmoid function

Tags: machine-learning, classification, logistic-regression

**Context:**

I picked up data-set from [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/bank+marketing) and tried to run Logistic Regression on it. Since I am not very much aware of MATLAB, I converted "Strings" to "Numbers" with my own using "NUMBERS" software.

**What I want to achieve:**

After running the LR algorithm when I tried to predict the value of existing data points, I am getting values ranging between 0-1 (as it should be), but since my job it to predict whether it is either 0 (yes) or 1 (no), that means I need to find a cut-off line (threshold) in my prediction (This could probably be done by comparing actual value by predicted value).

**Question**:

How can I figure out the threshold for predicted result such that result is assumed to be 1 if predicted value > threshold, otherwise 0?

Predicted values can be [found here.](https://github.com/guptakvgaurav/ml-practice/blob/master/result_predict_val.txt)
I am assuming predicted values are correct as [cost curve](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guptakvgaurav/ml-practice/master/cost_curve.png) is showing asymptotic nature. I have pushed [my work here](https://github.com/guptakvgaurav/ml-practice), you may want to cross-validate and provide me few more key points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Andrew Ng's Course, if you use the sigmoid activation, the outputs represent the probability of either outcome 0 or outcome 1.

So the decision boundary is 0.5

if prediction > 0.5 , the prediction is 1

if prediction <= 0.5 , the prediction in 0

Here's a screenshot from Andrew Ng's [slides](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJWfVf69C4k):

[image]

I have gone through your code and results. There seems to be something wrong with the implementation as none of your predictions give a value greater than 0.5 .

I couldn't pin down the problem. Some debugging will be needed on your side.

What's paradoxical is that your loss is reducing. I suspect this might be because **your data set is unbalanced** i.e., you have 221 0s and about 30 1s. This could be the reason for other problems as well.

Consider the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) example, where the values are correctly matching.
[image]

If you manage to find the error or the solution conclusively, please post it here so that we can all learn.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If data is unbalanced, the OP could use class weights... sklearn [logistic regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) uses: `n_samples / (n_classes * bincount(y))`.